# As a programmer how can I write applications on Juju provisioned infrastructure?

Tags: juju, maas, docker, continuous-deployment

I have been reading up on Juju 2.0 and done a few basic tutorials to install juju and deploy some charms on my local machine. I have also setup a MAAS server. What I want to do is write some applications on my localhost and deploy them to my MAAS server using Juju.

How can I do this? Am I using the right paradigm? I thought Juju is analogous to Docker compose and I've used Docker in a Continuous Delivery pipeline so that my local environment is similar to production for quick repeatable deployments.

[Using MAAS with Juju](https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.3/clouds-maas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juju makes it easy to quickly deploy services and applications on your infrastructure(MAAS in your case). To deploy your applications you will have to create a charm first that will install and launch your application. Information on writing charms can be found [here](https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.3/authors-charm-writing). Once your charms is build you can then deploy your application by deploying your charm.

To deploy them to your MAAS will have to add the MAAS to your clouds in juju (link in your post) and then bootstrap your controller there.